# injecting interface with multiple implementations in play framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework

I want to inject java interface using @Inject annotation but since there are multiple implementations of this interface, I am not getting how play framework will resolve I am trying to find something like the qualifier annotation in spring but am unable to found something like this in play documentation.  Please let me know how this can be achieved.

```
interface i1 {
    void m1() {}
}
class c1 implements i1{}
class c2 implements i1{}

class c {
    @Inject 
    i1 i; // which instance will be injected here how to resolve this conflict.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework use Guice:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaDependencyInjection
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation

You can achieve it in different ways. The simplest examples:

1. **Binding annotations**

If you need only one realization.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Binding-annotations

```
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy;

@ImplementedBy(c1.class)
public interface i1 {
    void m1();
}
```

2. **Programmatic bindings**

If you need a few realizations of the same class. Similar to a qualifier. The one you asked for.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;

public class Module extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {

    bind(i1.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("c1"))
      .to(c1.class);

    bind(i1.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("c2"))
      .to(c2.class);
  }
}
```

Later in the code

```
@Inject @Named("c1")
i1 i;
```